# How to prove $\frac{d}{dx}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x}{(4-x^2)^n} \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1-2n}{(4-x^2)^n}+\frac{8n}{(4-x^2)^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus

How to prove

$$\frac{d}{dx}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x}{(4-x^2)^n}
    \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1-2n}{(4-x^2)^n}+\frac{8n}{(4-x^2)^{n+1}}$$

I get stuck at

$$\frac{d}{dx}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x}{(4-x^2)^n}
    \end{bmatrix}=\frac{(4-x^2)^n+2n(4-x^2)^{n-1}x^2}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}$$

Comment: Can you tell me where did i go wrong ?

Comment: It is no wrong. You just have to simplify above expression and you will be able to see that it is equal to the one below

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: For a start, extract a common factor from numerator and denominator.

Comment: Just because something looks like a quotient doesn’t mean that you have to use the quotient rule. If you use the product rule instead you’ll get a simpler expression to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{(4-x^2)^n+2n(4-x^2)^{n-1}x^2}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}=\frac{(4-x^2)^n}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}+\frac{2n(4-x^2)^{n-1}x^2}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{(4-x^2)^n}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}+\frac{2n(4-x^2)^{n-1}x^2}{(4-x^2)^{2n}}=\frac{1}{(4-x^2)^n}+\frac{2nx^2}{(4-x^2)^{n+1}}
$$
Now substitute $2nx^2=8n-2n(4-x^2)$ into the second numerator
$$
\frac{1}{(4-x^2)^n}+\frac{2nx^2}{(4-x^2)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{(4-x^2)^n}+\frac{8n-2n(4-x^2)}{(4-x^2)^{n+1}}
$$
and simplify to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your answer let $$2nx^2=-2n(4-x^2)+8n$$ and simplify to get the given answer.